# Python socket server new line issue

Tags: python, sockets

so I am making a socket server in python but every time a message is sent it does a new line like this

```
Rank: Admin
Rank Password: **Censored**
Nickname: SomeoneElse
[Admin
] Testusername
: hello
```

but what I want it to Receive is
    [Admin] Testusername: hello 
but every time the code is asking for the nickname rank and message with %s it does a new line here is the code being used

```
def rank(conn, prefix="Rank: "):
    conn.send(prefix)
    return conn.recv(512)

def nickname(conn, prefix="Nickname: "):
    conn.send(prefix)
    return conn.recv(512)

rank = rank(conn)
nickname = nickname(conn)

message = conn.recv(512)
if message:
    reply = "[%s] %s: %s" % (rank, nickname, message)
    broadcast(reply, conn)
else:
    remove(conn)


def broadcast(message, connection):
    for cons in bc:
        if cons != connection:
            try:
                cons.sendall(message)
            except:
                cons.close()
                remove(cons)

def remove(connection):
    if connection in bc:
        bc.remove(connection)
```

that is the code to the message system why is it doing a new line every time %s is used? btw I removed the other code cause its irrelevant to my question
I changed nickname to "nickname" so and it showed this

```
[Admin
] nickname: hi
```

Comment: Is it possible that `rank` and `nickname` are already newline terminated? You could test this by temporarily using: `reply = "[%s] %s: %s" % (rank, 'nickname', message)` to see if a hardcoded `"nickname"` prints ok.

Comment: refresh i just edited

Comment: i did what you said and it made a change 
[Admin
] nickname: hi
nickname was not on a third line now its line 2

Comment: Can you update your question with this information so that we can see the exact formatting of the output that you see?

Comment: i just updated it

Comment: You probably want your functions to return `conn.recv(512).rstrip('\r\n')` or some such. You'll also want to encapsulate the receiving functionality so you don't repeat yourself and have the same bug in two places.

Comment: even with rstrip it still does the issue

Comment: You may have to try different combinations: `rstrip()`, `rstrip('\n')` etc.

Comment: i have just tried all the combos with rstrip and it didnt fix it

Comment: You need to find out exactly what your client is sending back to you. It could be anything!

Comment: i guess there is no fix